# Solving the Inequality $\frac{14x}{x+1}<\frac{9x-30}{x-4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

The question says to find all the integral values of x for which the inequality holds.
the question is

$$\frac{14x}{x+1}<\frac{9x-30}{x-4}$$

**My Solution**

\begin{align}
& \frac{14x}{x+1} < \frac{9x-30}{x-4} \\[6pt]
& \frac{14x(x-4)-(9x-30)(x+1)}{(x+1)(x-4)}<0 \\[6pt]
& \frac{14x^2-64x-9x^2+21x+30}{(x+1)(x-4)} < 0 \\[6pt]
& \frac{5x^2-43x+30}{(x+1)(x-4)}<0
\end{align}

using quadratic formula, roots of $5x^2-43x+30$ comes $7.83$(approx.) and $0.763$(approx.)

so rewriting the equation as

$$\frac{(x-7.83)(x-0.763)}{(x+1)(x-4)}<0$$

I then did the plotting of zeroes and poles on number line for finding the values for $x$ but I donot get 2 integral values (which is the answer). Can anyone tell where I did wrong?

Comment: Well take their intersection with $\mathbb Z$

Comment: You made mistake, you should get $\frac{5x^2=35x+30}{(x+1)(-4)}<0$ or equivalently $\frac{5(x-1)(x-6)}{(x+1)(x-4)}<0$.

Comment: I took but i get 4 integral values 0,5,6,7 but the answer says it has only two possible integral values

Comment: @alans i also thought that i made a mistake there but i am not able to figure out what is the mistake i did.

Comment: I deleted all the inappropriate "equals" signs.  Those should be used ONLY when you're saying things are equal. $\qquad$

Comment: @danny in 3. equation is mistake. There should be $4*14=56$

Comment: @danny: $14 \times 4 = 56$, not $64$.  There's your mistake.

Comment: @alans I got  it ..hehe..silly mistake can ruin an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inequality is equivalent with $$\frac{(x-1)(x-6)}{(x+1)(x-4)}<0.$$ Function $f(x)=\frac{(x-1)(x-6)}{(x+1)(x-4)}$ has sign $+$ on intervals $(-\infty,-1)$, $(1,4)$, $(6,\infty)$ and sign $-$ on intervals $(-1,1)$ and $(4,6)$.

Therefore, only integer solutions that satisfy inequality are $0$ and $5$.

Answer (score 2):

**Basic approach.** Perhaps easier would be to rewrite the original inequality as

$$
14 - \frac{14}{x+1} < 9 + \frac{6}{x-4}
$$

This leads to

$$
\frac{14}{x+1} + \frac{6}{x-4} > 5
$$

which becomes

$$
\frac{4x-10}{(x+1)(x-4)} > 1
$$

You can now (a) consider the cases $x = 0, 1, 2, 3$ separately, and then otherwise, (b) for $x < -1$ or $x > 4$, we have

$$
(x+1)(x-4) < 4x-10
$$

which becomes

$$
x^2-7x+6 < 0
$$

which you should be able to handle.  Keep in mind that this inequality is only valid for the subcase (b) $x < -1$ or $x > 4$.

(There's probably a simpler way, incidentally.  See alans' comment, for instance.  This is just what I wrote up.)

Comment: $x^2-7x+6<0$ is equivalent with $1<x<6$, which is not solution (take $x=2$ as eample). You shouldn't multiply with $(x+1)(x-4)$, that caused mistake.

Comment: @alans: I left it a little unclear, but that section is prefaced with "otherwise, for $x < -1$ or $x > 4$."  In conjunction with $1 < x < 6$, that leaves $x = 5$.  The other solution, $x = 0$, is found by direct inspection. ¶ Did you downvote?

Comment: Yes, I downvoted, sorry, it was unclear. I'll fix that now.

Comment: @alans: It was worth noting that it was unclear.  +1 to you too! :-)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to solve is to consider the corresponding equation.  A change of sings can only occur due to continuity at the equation's zeros or where the equation is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting your initial mistake will lead to the inequality

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{(x+1)(x-6)}{(x+1)(x-4)}<0
\end{equation}

which is positive on the interval $(6,\infty)$ since the product of $x$ coefficients is positive, and the expression changes sign at each zero and pole as you move left along the $x$-axis since each of the four linear factors is raised to an odd power. Thus it is negative only on the intervals $(-1,1)$ and $(4,6)$.

So the only integral solutions are $x=0$ and $x=5$.